# How to use empty arrays to fill in quantities

Tags: javascript, arrays

The length of an array is fixed at 5.

I want to fill the length with an empty array if the length is less than 5, and arrange it in order.

How to do that?

```
test = [
    ["qwe","0"],
    ["ewq","2"],
    ["aaa","4"],
]
```

becomes

```
test = [
    ["qwe","0"],
    ["",""],
    ["ewq","2"],
    ["",""],
    ["aaa","4"],
    ["",""],
]
```

Comment: please add an approch.why should be the filled parts inbetween. what happens if you have a different requirement, like have three want four?

Comment: You have mention length is 5 and you have 6 elements?? Please provide more info

Answer (score 2):

## Algorithm

1. Convert your `array` to a `map` with the second item of the array as it's keys. You can use [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) for this step
2. Create an empty array of size equal to `size + 1`
3. Map each item in your array using [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) . If its index is in the map then recreate the item in the previous array. Else fill it with an *"empty"* slot `["", ""]`
4. Call the function described in `3` with the `size` and the `map` described in `1`

## Implementation

```js
// Convert your array to a map
const fillArray = (m, size) => Array(size + 1).fill(0).map((x, idx) => `${idx}` in m ? [m[idx], `${idx}`] : ['', '']);

// Fill the array "in between"
const getArrayMap = arr => arr.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  acc[curr[1]] = curr[0];
  return acc;
}, {});

// Data
const size = 5;
const test = [
  ["qwe", "0"],
  ["ewq", "2"],
  ["aaa", "4"],
];

const filled = fillArray(getArrayMap(test), size);
console.log(filled);
```

## Notes

- You can optimize this by running a check before executing anything to test if `size - 1 < test.length`. If that's the case you don't need to run any function
- You can make this more robust by filtering the `test` array and removing all items that do not follow the *"standard shape"*. For example with `test.filter(x => x.length === 2)`